# Reading PDF plots, arranging them on a grid, save in one-page PDF using R

Tags: r, pdf, pdftk

I have 3 R plots saved as pdf files (`upper_left.pdf`, `upper_right.pdf`, `lower.pdf`) as vector graphic and want to make a **one-page pdf file** and arrange them on it as follows:

[image: Three plots in one page]

### What I have tried already

I have tried reading the pdf's using `magick::image_read_pdf` and appending them using `magick::image_append`. More specifically,

```r
library(magick)

panel.ul <- image_read_pdf("upper_left.pdf")
panel.ur <- image_read_pdf("upper_right.pdf")
panel.l <- image_read_pdf("lower.pdf")

whole <- c(panel.ul, panel.ur) %>% 
    image_append() %>% 
    c(panel.l) %>% 
    image_append(stack = TRUE)
```

The first issue is `magick::image_read_pdf` imports the plot as `png` (if I'm right, not vector graphic though).

`magick::image_append` also 'works' and gives me what I want in `viewer` pane (in RStudio, next to `Help`).

I then try to save them using `export::graph2pdf(whole)`, but it gives me a blank page.

So, if I am to use `magick`, there are two issues that need to be solved:

1. importing plots as vector graphic objects (do not know the technical term in R)
2. Exporting the stacked plot to a vector pdf file.

How can I solve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagemagick is a raster image processor. Any vector files will be rasterized when read. So you cannot save them again as pure vector. They will be raster files in a PDF vector shell. Imagemagick is not the right tool for doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42. I see now. What would you suggest instead to do the job?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what to suggest, since I have never done that.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically done. You only need to add

```
plot(whole) # plot the external object generated in ImageMagick to R's plotting device
savePlot(type = "pdf") # saves the current plotting device to a pdf file.
```

You will find your plot in your workoing directory called "Rplot.pdf".
savePlot has many options to customize your pdf output. Make sure to check `?savePlot`.

To recreate your scheme from above youll need to temporarily save the upper panel as a separate pdf before you paste it to on top of the lower panel:

```
whole2 <- image_append(c(panel.ul, panel.ur))
plot(whole2)
savePlot("whole2.pdf", type = "pdf")
```

If the upper and lower panel do not look proportionate you can use the heght and width parameters of savePlot to adjust the size of the first pdf.

```
panel.upr <-   image_read_pdf("whole2.pdf")
final <-  image_append(c(image_append(panel.upr),panel.l), stack = TRUE)
plot(final)
savePlot("final.pdf", type = "pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks Gerada. There are two issues still: first, the output is not vector anymore (apparently that's either `magick`'s fault or that of R's `plot()`). The other issue is that the output has a lot of white space around it and `savePlot` (apparently) doesn't allow costume size (`graph2pdf` can do that, but it still exports as non-vector graph) P.S. the sizes are already proportionate: the two on top are 5*5 inches each, the lower panel is 10*10 (so the 3-panel will be 10*20 in principal).

Comment: The image magick library is for processing bitmaps only. When it reads PDF, it converts it to a bitmap, sorry. I don't think it is possible to render a PDF as vector graphics on R's devices. Also, it might not be the best tool for combining PDFs.

Comment: I never said that I want to render PDF. Both the code in the question and my response read pdfs into ImageMagick, which than turns them into a graphic format and glues them together (still as a picture), than I plot this picture onto R's graphic device with the plot() function and create PDFs with R's function savePlot.(not with IM)