# Put multiple PDFs on none page, and repeat this for a list of files

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have done 2000 analyses, each named by a string containing spaces, numbers, and parentheses, and every analysis has produced three (vector) pdf files. For example, for analysis `John Doe 7 (m)` I have the following pdfs: `John Doe 7 (m)_upper_left.pdf`, `John Doe 7 (m)_upper_right.pdf`, `John Doe 7 (m)_lower.pdf` as want to make a **one-page pdf file** for `John Doe 7 (m)`, where they are arranged as follows in `John Doe 7 (m)_whole`:

[image: Three plots in one page]

And do this for all other analyses (`Jake Levinson 
 12 (k)`, ...), and have 2000 single-page, three-panel pdf files. [As I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020571/reading-pdf-plots-arranging-them-on-a-grid-save-in-one-page-pdf-using-r), I tried doing this in R for one analysis (so I can do it for other files) but the problem is R converts the plots into bitmap while reading them.

I'm on windows and have `pdftk` on my machine (if that helps). Is there a neat way of doing it using command line or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Does *"something else"* include programming in Java or c#/.Net?

Comment: Only if that is suitable for someone with zero knowledge of those languages. For instance, I have tried Multivalent [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466110/2275986) but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hhmmm, I was thinking of actual programming...

Comment: @mkl I hope I'll be able to figure out if the solution is clear.