# Batch converting EPS/PDF to postscript

Tags: pdf, batch-processing, ghostscript, postscript, eps

I'm on windows and am trying to convert 6000 PDF files in batch to postscript files. The reason is I'm trying to do pdf imposition as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027588/put-multiple-pdfs-on-none-page-and-repeat-this-for-a-list-of-files), first wanted to do in R as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020571/reading-pdf-plots-arranging-them-on-a-grid-save-in-one-page-pdf-using-r). I found a library `grImport` to handle vector graphics in R, but it needs .ps files.

I could already convert batch .pdf files to .eps using Inkscape using this [script](https://gist.github.com/JohannesDeml/779b29128cdd7f216ab5000466404f11). However, I need .ps for the R package. I was unable to do it using Adobe Acrobat Pro [Action](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Batch-converting-to-ps-files-q233491.aspx) (it simply doesn't work on the folder, and freezes when I try it on an individual file.)

I have also tried ghostscript but setting `-sDEVICE=pswrite` throws an error saying the device is unknown. Also, I really could not get my head around GS.

How can I do this? (If you happen to know a solution to the main problem, sharing it is very appreciated.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: EPS files work fine as PS files if you append ` showpage` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The pswrite device was deprecated years ago (it only produced level 1, big, ugly, unscalable output). You want to use the ps2write device which produces level 2 PostScript.

A simple command line for Ghostscript woudl be:

gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -o out.ps input.pdf

There are tools for imposing PDF files, you can even (with some effort) do it with Ghostscript.